# How to create parameters in VS 2010 snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

Hi I would like to create a Visual Studio snippet that I can have predefined values to...

for instance

```
<Timeline AutoPlay="$True|FALSE$">
```

Is there a way to do this?

Is there a tag other than Default that will allow me to add possible values?

```
    <CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet>
        <Header>

            <!-- Add Header information here -->

        </Header>
        <Snippet>

            <!-- Add additional Snippet information here -->

            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>SqlConnString</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Replace with a SQL connection string.</ToolTip>
                    **<Value>"Value1"</Value>
                    <Value>"Value2"</Value>**
                    <Default>"SQL connection string"</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Object>
                    <ID>SqlConnection</ID>
                    <Type>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection</Type>
                    <ToolTip>Replace with a connection object in your application.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>dcConnection</Default>
                </Object>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[
                    daCustomers = new SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                    selectCommand = new SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlConnString$);
                    daCustomers.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
                    daCustomers.SelectCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection$;
                ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Hallmark of good design.  You can endlessly come up with things you want to include.  Good design is knowing what to *leave out*.  Snippets were designed for programmers.

Comment: yeah that is why you add more features, no one actually needs all of MS office functionality but some people actually do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want macro replacement in a Visual Studio Snippet.  Unfortunately this is not really possible.  Visual Studio snippets only support a very small number of replacement macros and they are not user controllable.

Comment: What I would like is to have values on a drop down menu other than a Default value. Some sort of Assisted Code completion.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I hate when it happens to me, but here we go:

Q: How do I do X in Visual Studio?

A: Use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

in your case "Code Templates".

Comment: I use VA X, since it's . Can I create option lists in ReSharper templates or does it work in a similar fashion to VA?

Comment: not VA X user, so haven't got a clue.

this will be a good start: There's good overview: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html